# How can I prove the integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Prove that 
$$
\int\frac{dx}{x(\log_e x)^{7/8}} = 8(\log_e x)^{1/8}
$$

I am totally lost on this subject. Any help how to prove this is appreciated!

Comment: Isn't that x in the denominator screaming : **PUT** $\log_e x=t$?

Comment: If you only need to *prove* that this is true, i.e. if you already *know* the right-hand side, then it sufficies to differentiate the claimed antiderivative and see if that yields the integrals. In other words, check if $\frac{d}{dx} 8(\log_e x)^\frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{x(\log_e x)^\frac{7}{8}}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\log_e(x)) = \dfrac 1x$.

Putting $u = \log_e x \implies du = \frac 1x\,dx$.

That gives you:

$$ \int \frac{dx}{x(\log_e x)^{7/8}} = \int (\underbrace{\log_e x}_{u})^{-7/8}\cdot \underbrace{\left(\frac 1x \,dx \right)}_{du}=\int u^{-7/8} \,du$$

Can you take it from here (using the power rule)?

SPOILER (Scroll over to check your work!)

> $$\int u^{-7/8}\,du = \frac{u^{1/8}}{1/8} + C = 8u^{1/8} + C = 8(\log_e x)^{1/8} + C$$

Answer (score 1):

Firstly lets go with the convention of $ \log_ex=\ln x $, now $(\ln x)'=\frac {1}{x}$ so we have:

$\int (\frac {1}{x}(\ln x)^{-7/8})dx=\int(\ln x)^{-7/8})d(\ln x)=8(\ln x)^{1/8}+C$

Comment: No worries,  happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If you have meant,$$\int\frac{dx}{x\{\log_e(e\cdot x)\}^{\dfrac78}}$$

As $\ln(ex)=\ln e+\ln x=1+\ln x$

Substitute this with $u$

---

If you have meant,$$\int\frac{dx}{x(\log_ex)^{\dfrac78}}$$

Substitute $\log_ex$ with $v$

Comment: I believe that it was $\log_e x$, not $\log(ex)$.

Comment: @Victoria, Please confirm the Question

Comment: I meant the second one. Where is u?

Comment: @Victoria, As $$\frac{d(\log_ex)}{dx}=\frac1x,$$ we substitute $\log_ex$ to any variable

Answer (score 0):

Hint: set $t=\log_e x$, so $dt=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$